# How to make custom references in an Excel row with specific rules ? with VBA or Excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

I Want to **customise automatically** in **Excel** a **Reference number** according to the content of the line it is representing.

I have a table for test procedure that looks like this :

| Ref | Action | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A 001 | Name of the **Action** to perform | Empty if it is an **Action** |
| C 001 | Empty if it is a **Check** | Name of the **Check** to perform |
| C 002 | Empty if it is a **Check** | Name of the **Check** to perform |
| C 003 | Empty if it is a **Check** | Name of the **Check** to perform |
| A 002 | Name of the **Action** to perform | Empty if it is an **Action** |

**The logic would be the following:**

To iterate separately references starting with **A** and the ones starting with **C** depending on the type of procedure, that is to say whether the name of the procedure is in `Action Column` or `Check Column`.

I would like to implement an algorithm like this, or a formula that does the same thing :

```
For line in TABLE1 : 
    if ( TABLE1[line,Action] =! NULL && TABLE1[line,Check] = 0) :
            Ref_Action = Ref_Action + 1
        Ref_Code = "A" + Ref_Action
        elif ( TABLE1[line,Action] =! NULL && TABLE1[line,Check] = 0) :
            Ref_Check = Ref_Check + 1
        Ref_Code = "C"+ Ref_Check
        else raise error : "a procedure shall be either an action or a Procedure"

    TABLE1[line,Ref] = Ref_Code
```

(It is not a code language, just my way of representing the algorithm, I hope it is readable.)

Unfortunately, I have no experience in VBA and I couldn't find a way to write an appropriate formula. Or maybe there is another way ?

Thank you,

Gautier

Comment: If you have the logic and know to use jargon like `for` and `else`, you can code this :)

Comment: Columns Ref, ProcedureType and Procedure might be easier to deal with: you can expand "ProcedureType" to include more types, and add rows if a Ref gets more than one procedure.